# Doubts about how to migrate WordPress from local to online server using Search and Replace Tool script

Tags: installation, migration, server, localhost, local-installation

I am trying to migrate my blog from my local web server to an online web server and I have a doubt about this procedure.

I have uploaded all my local file in the root of my web server.

I have also export the tables of my local database (using phpMyAdmin) and I have import them on my online database.

Then I have change the settings inside the file **wp-config.php** in such a way as to make the connection with the online database.

Now I have to change the URL settings on my database using the **Search and Replace Tool** script: http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

So my doubts related to the use of the search and replace script are:

1) Have I to put the **searchreplacedb2.php** file into the root of my webserver (where it is the wp-config.php file) and have I to execute this script?

2) Have I to scann ALL the tables or only the posts table?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: Have you solved the issue or still need a help?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is simple.
Place the file in the root of the website.
Access this file via web browser.
For example. type - www.yoursite.com/searchreplacedb2.php

In the page, enter your database details, including username and password.
Also, specify your localhost http address, which in most cases is localhost

For example, in my testing server, my development files are usually in subfolders, so my link in local host is, localhost/site-1/

Likewise, enter your localmachine server url (localhost) and enter the new domain name there, i.e. yoursite.com

Select all the tables.

and press go. thats it...

Comment: mmm but where have I to put and use the searchreplacedb2.php script file? On my local web server or on my online web server?

Comment: Hi, @AndreaNobili you can either put it in the local server or on your online web server. I would recommend to use it online, since you could continue development on your local site without interrupting any settings or altering your database. Anyways, its your call... :D... Oh, BTW, dont forget to delete that script from your server once you are done with it. Simply delete it using FTP or through the file manager in Cpanel.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to give my [WP Migrate DB](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/) plugin a try. It exports your database and does all the find & replaces you need at the same time. Then you jump into phpMyAdmin to import it.

I recently released a [pro version](http://deliciousbrains.com/wp-migrate-db-pro/) that allows you to push or pull the database from your WordPress dashboard. No phpMyAdmin needed. Big time saver.